# Horizontal lifts of $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections

Let $p:E\longrightarrow B$ be a surjective submersion and $\sigma: p^*(TB)\longrightarrow TE$ be a complete connection. For a curve $\gamma:[a, b]\longrightarrow B$ and a point $e\in E_{\gamma(a)}$ we **the horizontal lift of $\gamma$ at $e$** which is a horizontal curve $\gamma_e^h: [a, b]\longrightarrow E$ such that $p\circ \gamma_h^e=\gamma$ and $\gamma_e^h(0)=e$.

What is the relationship between the horizontal lifts of $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$? Here $\gamma^{-1}(t):=\gamma(1-t)$.

I thought it should be something like $$(\gamma^{-1})^h_e=\gamma^h_{(\gamma^{-1})^h_e(1)},$$ but it does not seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal lift of $\gamma^{-1}$ at $\gamma^{-1}(0)=\gamma^h(1)$ is ${{\gamma^h}}^{-1}(t)=\gamma^h(1-t)$. This curve is tangent to the distribution which defines the connection and verifies $p({{\gamma^h}}^{-1}(t))=\gamma^{-1}(t)$.

Comment: Thanks, but you are not making reference to the points which they start. I mean, for every point $e\in E_{\gamma(a)}$ we will have some $\gamma^h$..

Comment: Sorry, but is not precise yet. If you take $e\in E_{\gamma^{-1}(0)}$ then what will be the point $x$ you shall take on $E_{\gamma(0)}$ so that $\gamma^h_x=(\gamma^{-1})^h_e$?

Comment: I take $e=\gamma^h(1)$

Comment: You are forgetting the $x$ in $e=\gamma^h_x(1)$ (if you change the $x$ we will have different curves). I mean, $\gamma^h(1)$ is correct..

Comment: I use the fact that the horizontal lift of $\gamma$ defines a diffeomorphism between $E_{\gamma(a)}$ and $E_{\gamma(b)}$ thus for every $f\in E_{\gamma(b)}$  there exists a unique point $e$ in $E_{\gamma(a)}$ whose horizontal lift is $f$.

Comment: I think you're talking about the holonomy of $\gamma$, then I agree with what you said, but I'm just thinking about the horizontal lift of curves. But I'll have to think a moment about it..

Comment: The relationship I was looking for was $(\gamma^{-1})^h_{\gamma^h_e(1)}=(\gamma^h_e)^{-1}$.